# .js file not running in firefox - code added along

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Is there something wrong with these files? I'm trying to view the output on my Firefox browser, and I'm unable to do it. Nothing comes to display. It's just a blank screen.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. Any help would be appreciated.

These are my files

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <pre id='json' style='white-space: pre-wrap'></pre>
 </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var req = {
    format: 'json',
    action: 'parse',
    page: 'New York City',
    prop: 'text',
    section: 0
};

$.ajax({
    url: '//simple.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
    data: req,
    cache: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(result) {
        // Add result's HTML to the top of the <body>
        $('body').prepend(result.parse.text['*']);
        // Append full JSON result to output
        $('#json').text(JSON.stringify(result, '', 2));
    }
});
});
```

Comment: That url looks wrong. You should probably have a protocol on it: `"http://simple.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"`

Comment: You're using jQuery, but the library isn't defined. Add it before main script.

Comment: And where exactly are you including the jQuery (?) library you are using?

Comment: I was using an online editor. And the code worked fine there. The script is not getting added to the html page it seems.

Comment: Try debugging with a console (firefox/chrome), this solves many problems.